# How to get innerHeight of fullscreen browser

Tags: javascript, browser

I know that I can get browser height in fullscreen without windows taskbar with winodw.availHeight. But I want to know the height without scrollbar, adress bar etc. too. I cant use innerHeight because if browser is not fullscreen, I still want to get fullscreen inner height.
thank you (and sorry for my English)

Answer (score 1):

`window.innerHeight` works perfectly. It gave me 455 when it was full screen and 340 when not full screen.

Check for yourself - Type `window.innerHeight` when normal and then click F11 and then do the same. You'll see different value. So it does differ.

Comment: I meant that I WANT to get same values